# Congrats to Ross Millikan AND Davide Giraudo

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, badges, specific-user

This just in. Ross Millikan has joined J.M. in the exclusive club of users who have cast at least 10000 votes. Congrats and thanks!

As per Julien's suggestion I'm also soliciting opinions from members, whether a related badge would be a good idea?

---

Davide Giraudo joined in this club, too. Congrats and thanks!

### Now we have a triumvirate of Senators!

Comment: And only $57$ down. To turn your question into a question, you could ask if people think that there should be a specific badge for this achievement. But maybe that would be on meta.so in this case.

Comment: How do we see how many votes we have cast?

Comment: @Potato: It's on the summary on your profile page.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Congratulations for the very first coding-theory badge ever earned!

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that there already exists a gold badge related to voting. It is called [electorate](http://math.stackexchange.com/badges/44/electorate):
*Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.*

Comment: @MartinSleziak Sure. But $600$ looks pale compared to $10 000$. This raises a question: should there be platinum badges for overachievers who are already legendary and the like?

Comment: Agree with julien in that 600 votes is a trivial thing. A noob determined to get a gold badge can achieve that by random voting in a month. Not that anyone would do such a thing. With the members of this club we know that the votes are meaningful. In other words the two gentlemen have actually read 10000+ posts, and given their nod of approval (or in rarer cases disproval). That's commitment.

Comment: ^three!!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Congratulations to both of you. Thanks Jyrki for noting us it. ;-)

Comment: Congratulations to both of you too. :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Probably a "Senator" badge, in the gold badges category. Anyone have other ideas for the name?

Comment: That has a nice ring to it.

Comment: I've always wondered if there should be platinum badges followed by gold-platinum badges. I look at some of the contributors to MSE and they have over 100k of reputation, some have reviewed many postings, voted a lot, et. al. It seems like they should receive some token for the long contributions as acknowledgment. I have also found it odd with some of the limits on things, for example, how many edits to postings. I would think we would want contributors doing that forever. My 2 cents.

Comment: Accepting this answer for now. Not because there wouldn't be good alternatives (and something better may come up later), but simply to allow this question to drift to the background. I like the *Senator* suggestion because it has that statesmanly air to it.

Answer (score 12):

Anything likely to increase the number of votes per user seems like a good idea to me. I might be wrong, but I have the feeling that the more people vote, the more meaningful the overall scores are. Not in the sense that they would suddenly become 100% fair and accurate. But they would be closer to a representation of the majority's opinion. Which is the main meaning I attribute to them. Except for the cases when I post a silly answer and get the deserved downvotes which I then take as a wake-up call.

I would propose a gold "democracy" badge. And I would also impose a maximum ratio of downvotes, say $25\%$. Even if I'm not sure how to justify this.

Comment: Would you prefer instead of downvotes to have a comment "*Silly julien, silliness is for kidsandkidsatheartliketheMontyPythonguysohmygodhowawesomeistheHolyGrailmovie?AMIRITE??*" or something similar? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila He, he. I think that a comment indicating what is wrong with the answer is even more helpful. But a silly comment on a silly answer is not a bad option eiher. I would gladly welcome that.

Comment: @julien since this was your brilliant idea to increase peoples voting could you post this suggestion as feature-request-question on meta?

Comment: @Norbert I was not planning to do that. But you are welcome to do it!

Comment: @julien [done](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/suggestion-for-new-badge)