# Congratulations to André!

Tags: discussion, specific-user, celebration

Congratulations to [André Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andr%C3%A9-nicolas?tab=reputation) $300 K$ edition!!!!

Just writing this message to congratulate André for being the first user in MSE to reach 300 K.

Comment: Thank you!  I hope to go to the Santiago area when I go again to Cuba.

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for all the great answers.

Comment: Congrats @AndréNicolas. Thanks for helping me many times.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, the legend!

Comment: What’s at least as remarkable is that André has answered almost $3$% of the $365,500$ questions as of my writing this comment.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : When can we expect $\aleph_0$ ?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: If it were not for the sabbatical, your percentage would be greater.